# Inherited MS Access Database, Tracking Sources of Queries

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have just inherited a database at my new company.  Old DB owner left no good documentation and queries very hard to keep track of.  Looking for programmatic answer to track sources of fields in every query (what table it come from).  Prefer something can be exported to Excel to study, Access visualization is no good.  Am familiar with VBA.

Comment: This questions might be better served at: https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Take a look at: http://mdbdoc.sourceforge.net/ and http://www.accessdependencychecker.com/ to see if either will help. The first builds an HTML file of all objects that you could search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been through this with many inherited databases.  I find it extremely helpful to create an Access table with the fields and the tables/queries that they come from.  Try this code below.  It will prompt you for the name of the query that you are looking to "map" as I call it.  It will then create a new table named "queryName Definitions".

```
Option Compare Database

Public Sub MapQuery()

 Dim strQueryName As String
 Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
 Dim fld As Field
 Dim strSource As String
 Dim strField As String
 Dim strValue As String
 Dim strSQL1 As String
 Dim strSQL2 As String
 Dim booExists As Boolean


strQueryName = InputBox("Please enter the name of the query that you are looking to map")

   Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strQueryName)

On Error GoTo error1
    booExists = IsObject(CurrentDb.TableDefs(strQueryName & " Definitions"))
    DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, strQueryName & " Definitions"
continue:
    strSQL1 = "CREATE TABLE [" & strQueryName & " Definitions]" & " (FieldName CHAR, SourceName CHAR);"
    DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL1)
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    For Each fld In rst.Fields

    strField = fld.Name
    strSource = fld.SourceTable


Debug.Print strValue

    strSQL2 = "INSERT INTO [" & strQueryName & " Definitions]" & "(FieldName, SourceName) VALUES(""" & strField & """, """ & strSource & """);"

    DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL2)
    Next fld

error1:
    If Err.Number = 3265 Then
        Resume continue
    Else
    MsgBox Err.Description

    End If

    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    Exit Sub

    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks this exactly what I am looking for!

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty messy but could save you time collecting each query's SQL code. The following code exports all SQL stored in the QueryDefs collection into a text file. I have it splitting the code with a space delimiter, but a comma might be preferable. The data will not be normalized, I don't have the time to go to that level of complexity. Just make sure to update `strPath` before you execute. Hopefully this helps.

```
Sub PullQuerySQL()

    Dim dbs As Database
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim oFile As Object
    Dim varParse() As String
    Dim element As Variant
    Dim strPath As String

    strPath = ".txt"

    Set dbs = CurrentDb()
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile(strPath)

    For i = 0 To dbs.QueryDefs.Count - 1
        oFile.WriteLine dbs.QueryDefs(i).Name
        varParse = Split(dbs.QueryDefs(i).SQL, " ")
        For Each element In varParse
            oFile.WriteLine element
        Next element
    Next i

    oFile.Close

    Set oFile = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing

End Sub
```